# Crash Google Chrome for debugging

Tags: google-chrome, browser

How can I make Google Chrome crash?

I need to crash the browser not just a tab.
https://www.google.com/search?q=Whoa!+Google+Chrome+has+crashed&um=1&tbm=isch

What I really need is to automatically restart browser when it crashes. In order to do that I need to be able to test it by crashing chrome on demand.

Or better is there a command line option to suppress this dialog?
 Tried --no-sandbox with no success.

Answer (score 2):

In response to your first question, you can cause Chrome to crash on demand by hitting chrome://inducebrowsercrashforrealz